# Set Minimum step size in ode15s

Tags: matlab, ode

I am calling ode15s within a genetic algorithm and for some configurations of the variables of the problem the integration step becomes too small and then a warning is raised.I don't mind the warning but this slows down the process of finding the solution. So,I want to make ode15s to quit earlier (faster). I thought I could increase the minimum step allowed,but I tried this

`options = odeset('AbsTol',1e-8,'RelTol',1e-5,'MinStep',1e-5);`

and did not work. What can I do?

Comment: As @user1980812 states, [there is no `'MinStep'` property](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/odeset.html) for any ODE solver. You might also try reducing the [`'MaxOrder'`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/odeset.html#f92-1023635) if your system isn't very stiff or using using [`ode23s`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode23s.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I refer to this post:
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/307359

You can't specify a minimum step! But changing the values for relTol and AbsTol will indirectly change the minimum step.

Good luck!